# JPA repository changes for getting data from two tables combining

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables Employee and Branch

```
  employee (
       emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
       first_name VARCHAR(40),
       last_name VARCHAR(40),
       birth_day DATE,
       sex VARCHAR(1),
       salary INT,
       super_id INT,
       branch_id INT
  );

   branch (
        branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        branch_name VARCHAR(40),
        branch_address VARCHAR(50),
        branch_pincode INT
    );
```

I have one query (select A.emp_id, A.first_name, A.last_name, A.birth_date, B.branch_id, B.branch_name, B.branch_address, B.branch_pincode from employee A, branch B where A.branch_id = B.branch_id;)

I have 2 interfaces of both entity employee_repo and branch_repo which are extending CrudRepository.
How will i get the data from this query from these repositories combined.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employee")
 public class Employee {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
     private Integer emp_id;

     private String first_name;
     private String last_name;
     ..
     ..
     //

     // with getters and setters...
  }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "branch")
 public class Branch {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
     private Integer branch_id;

     private String branch_name;
     private String branch_address;
     ..
     ..
     //

     // with getters and setters...
  }
```

I have tried this but not able to get to the solution

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employee")
 public class Employee {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
     private Integer emp_id;

     private String first_name;
     private String last_name;
     ..
     ..
     //

     // with getters and setters...
     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "branch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private Branch branch;

  }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "branch")
 public class Branch {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
     private Integer branch_id;

     private String branch_name;
     private String branch_address;
     ..
     ..
     //

     // with getters and setters...

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "branch_id")
     private Employee employee;
  }
```

Comment: please try                                                                                       '@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)                                                                                                 
 private Branch branch;'

Comment: @kamleshpandey where should i add it?

Comment: change  ** mappedBy = "branch" ** to ** mappedBy = "employee" ** in Employee class.